# ConnectionRequest when the app is in the background

Tags: codenameone

I've tested Geofence example by cn1 where it sets local notification. When the app is closed(get destroyed), it still gives notification. But I want to get location through GPS and run connectionRequest to save them in the server. I replaced the connectionRequest code instead of LocalNotification in following code but it doesnot work. What should I do to run the connectionRequest when the app is closed(not when it is minimized but destroyed) so that once the user installs and close (destroys) it, the app sent his/her location data in the server forever untill the app is uninstalled.

Geofence gf = new Geofence("test", loc, 100, 100000);
LocationManager.getLocationManager().addGeoFencing(GeofenceListenerImpl.class, gf);

Geofence with localNotification:

```
public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {
    @Override
    public void onExit(String id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEntered(String id) {
        if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                Dialog.show("Welcome", "Thanks for arriving", "OK", null);
            });
        } else {
            LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
            ln.setId("LnMessage");
            ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
            ln.setAlertBody("Thanks for arriving!");
            Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, 10, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
        }
    }    
}
```

Why the following doesnot work? (it only work when the app is running or is minimized but not when it is destroyed.)

```
public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {
    @Override
    public void onExit(String id) {
       System.out.println("geofence onExit");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEntered(String id) {
        if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                System.out.println("geofence isMinimized");
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("geofence when app is closed");
            //I want to run connectionRequest here but is not working
        }
    }    
}
```

PS. I've used background fetch but it only works when the app is minimized.

**Update1: Demo of how I used connectionRequest outside of minimized() method...**

```
public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {
    @Override
    public void onExit(String id) {
       System.out.println("geofence onExit");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEntered(String id) {
        if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("geofence when app is closed");
            Connection c = new Connection();
            c.liveTrackConnectionMethod("22" , "23");
        }
    }    
}
```

Connection class

```
public class Connection {

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> response;
    public void liveTrackConnectionMethod(String lat, String lon) {

        ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
                Map parser = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
                response = null;
            }
        };
        cr.setPost(true);
        cr.setUrl("http://url.com");
        cr.addArgument("userid", Preferences.get(AllUrls.userIdPreference, null));
        cr.addArgument("lat", lat + "");
        cr.addArgument("long", lon + "");
        cr.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `c.liveTrackConnectionMethod("22" , "23");` work outside the ifelse?

Comment: it works inside if...

Answer (score 1):

I think an app will always return `false` for `isMinimized()` when the app is closed or minimized (i.e. not currently running in the foreground) I may be wrong about this.

Try calling your `connectionRequest` script outside the `isMinimized()`. After all, you will want to keep track of user location whether they are using the app or not.

Your first solution with `LocalNotification` will show users a notification by calling the `else` part, rather than the `Dialog` when they're using the app, because `isMinimized()` will be `false`.

Comment: yeahh I did that. I've System.out.println("geofence when app is closed") in else part of the isMinimized(). While debugging, I don't see it after the app is closed. I've tried ConnectionRequest here as well but no effect.

Comment: There could be a problem with the `ConnectionRequest` script. Post your snippet in the answer to provide clarity. Remove sensitive data.

Comment: Hi, there's update1 with connectionRequest script above. And it works before app is closed( ie works before I remove it from the background as well). I've the same connection code in the minimized method as well

Comment: @Diamond is correct that isMinimized() will be true when the app is closed or minimized.  If that app isn't in the foreground, isMinimized() will return true.  So your logic here is backwards.  Your "app is closed" case should be if isMinimized() is true.  I have a few apps that make ConnectionRequests in a geofence handler, and they are working fine (with the app in the background or destroyed).

Comment: @stevehannah  isMinimized() is not working when the app is closed by swiping it out from the recent app list. If any other app is in foreground, isMinimized works. I want to know whether we can keep sending the data after the app is swiped out.

Comment: I don't think your app continues to receive geofence events after the user has swiped the app out of the app list (i..e force closes it).  I'm not 100% on that - but I'm fairly certain.  Are you still receiving these events after swipe out?